Transpose data in SQL with NULL values
I have a table with 6 columns like below



ID
VAL1
VAL2
VAL3
VAL4
VAL5




1234
AB
CD
NULL
DF
NULL


5678
HJ
NULL
UI
NULL
NULL



The expected results are like below. I want to transpose the data like below. NULL values shouldn't be considered while transposing.



ID
VALUE




1234
AB


1234
CD


1234
DF


5678
HJ


5678
UI



Can I achieve this in SQL? Thanks!

Which SQL database are you using?

UNION ALL of 5 SELECTs should work in most of DBMSes

One possible way which will work on almost every dbms is using UNION ALL. Then in an outer query filter all null VAL values.
Query,
SELECT id, VAL
FROM (
      SELECT id,val1 AS VAL FROM myTable
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT id,val2 FROM myTable
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT id,val3 FROM myTable
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT id,val4 FROM myTable
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT id,val5 FROM myTable
      ) tbl
WHERE VAL IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id ASC

This can be done without outer query as well, adding an where clause such as the following , but I would prefer using an outer query for readability .
SELECT id,val1 AS VAL FROM myTable
WHERE val1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT id,val2 FROM myTable
WHERE val2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT id,val3 FROM myTable
WHERE val3 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT id,val4 FROM myTable
WHERE val4 IS NOT NULL  
UNION ALL 
SELECT id,val5 FROM myTable
WHERE val5 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id ASC

See example

There are some functions such as UNPIVOT (SQL Server) etc but those are product specific and you need to tag the dbms used.

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, value1 as value
    FROM table_name
    WHERE value1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
    SELECT id, value2 as value
    FROM table_name
    WHERE value2 IS NOT NULL
) AS nt
ORDER BY id ASC

